# My while loop does not randomize my list, but begins to repeat the same words in the list

Tags: python

I created a while  loop to hope that it will randomize the lists but instead, it begins to repeat the same animals and same fruits.

```
import time
import random

animals = ['sheep','cow','cat','dog']
fruits = ['oranges','apples', 'banana']

ani = random.choice(animals)
fru = random.choice(fruits)

while True:
    print(ani+fru)
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: `random.choice` needs to be inside the loop body for that

Comment: You wrote a program to choose one random animal and one random fruit, then print that one combination forever.  Please repeat your tutorial on loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the random function inside loop if you want to change it every time.

Try this:

'''

```
animals = ['sheep','cow','cat','dog']
fruits = ['oranges','apples', 'banana']

while True:
    ani = random.choice(animals)
    fru = random.choice(fruits)
    print(ani+fru)
```

'''